# Compilation-time initialization of an array of struct with the information of another array

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, array-initialization

Let `Foo` be a structure holding an integer.

Now, I need to initialize at compilation time an array of `Foo` from the values coming from an array of integers.

Of course, one can hand-write it but having a generic way to do it (with some `ArrayInitializer` feature) would be of great help.

```
struct Foo { int n; };

constexpr int N = 3; // not necessary a literal but could come from a type trait value

int values [N] = {1,2,4};

// hand-written array initialization
Foo objects[N] = { Foo{values[0]}, Foo{values[1]}, Foo{values[2]} };

// is it possible to make it automatically ?
// Foo objects[N] = ArrayInitializer (N,objects,value);

int main () {}
```

**Question:** is it possible with meta-programming to design such an `ArrayInitializer` feature ? Or is it simply impossible and what is the reason why ?

Comment: Use `std::array<Foo, N>` and be happy.

Comment: Perhaps a `constexpr` template pack function and/or class utilizing [`std::integer_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence)? Haven't done anything with it personally, but I've seen some incredibly clever things with that. :)

Comment: @273K: I surely can use ```std::array``` but I don't see how it can help to answer to the question. Is there some special trick there with ```std::array``` ?

Comment: You can write a pretty straightforward function with a for loop and return a `std::array`, making your life a hundred times easier.

Comment: `std::array` can be returned. C array `T[N]` can't be returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `std::array<Foo, N>`, you might do something like:

```
template <std::size_t N>
constexpr std::array<Foo, N> make_foo_array(const int(& arr)[N])
{
    return [&]<std::size_t...Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
        return array<Foo, N>{{ Foo(arr[Is])... }};
    }(std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```

Above requires C++20, but can be rewritten for other standards.

Comment: You don't even have to use `index_sequence`, a for loop works just fine.

Comment: It depends if `Foo` is really default constructible...

Comment: @Jarod42: thank you for this answer. I had (vaguely) the idea to use something similar with ```std::index_sequence``` but I'm afraid it would have taken me a few days to finalize something working.

Comment: Just a remark: the input parameter ```const (int& arr)[N]``` seems odd to me (to g++ as well actually). What is it about ? I replaced by ```const int arr[N]``` to make it work on my snippet.

Comment: parameter `const int arr[N]` is `const int* arr`, I misplaced parenthesis, it should be: `const int (&arr)[N]`.