# C++ template container instantiation

Tags: c++

I have 2 classes, `Thing1` and `Thing2` in the example below.
`Thing2` requires `Thing1` in its constructor.
The code as shown in the example compiles.
However, I would like the instantiation of `thing2_pool` to look more like:

```
Thing2Container<count> thing2_pool(thing1_pool);
```

Where a wrapping template container would instantiate the `std::array<Thing2, count>` with the associated `thing1_pool` nodes passed into each `Thing2` constructor.

It seems there must be a way to do this, but I cannot seem to make it happen.
Here is the example code:

```
/**
 * @file templ.cc
 * Compiles with:  c++ -std=c++17 -Wall templ.cc
 * 
 * Instead of hard-coding the instantiation of thing2_pool, 
 * can a template class, using a recursive constructor (?), 
 * implement thing_pool2 construction / instantiation? 
 */
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>

class Thing1
{
public:
    // Only the default ctor is valid.
    Thing1() noexcept                    = default;
    Thing1(Thing1 const&)                = delete;
    Thing1(Thing1&&) noexcept            = delete;
    Thing1& operator=(Thing1 const&)     = delete;
    Thing1& operator=(Thing1&&) noexcept = delete;
};

class Thing2
{
public:
    // Only this single parameter ctor is valid:
    explicit Thing2(Thing1& t1) noexcept: thing1(t1) {}

    Thing2() noexcept                    = delete;
    Thing2(Thing2 const&)                = delete;
    Thing2(Thing2&&) noexcept            = delete;
    Thing2& operator=(Thing2 const&)     = delete;
    Thing2& operator=(Thing2&&) noexcept = delete;

    Thing1& get_thing1() { return this->thing1; }

private:
    Thing1& thing1;
};

static constexpr size_t count = 4u;

std::array<Thing1, count> thing1_pool;
std::array<Thing2, count> thing2_pool = {
    Thing2(thing1_pool[0u]),
    Thing2(thing1_pool[1u]),
    Thing2(thing1_pool[2u]),
    Thing2(thing1_pool[3u]),
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78116330/compilation-time-initialization-of-an-array-of-struct-with-the-information-of-an) could be helpful.

Comment: Chat bot? If you mean Chat GPT, remember that it's a language model not a real AI, and the language that it's modelling isn't C++. Take what it tells you with a grain of salt.

Comment: Thank you @edrezen for answering this. I'm going to answer my own question based on their previous Q & A as edrezen posted as a comment.

Comment: @natersoz: you're welcome; I'm glad a human can still beat a bot ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78116423/138264) Question and Answer:
I will work on improving this perhaps.

```
template <std::size_t N, typename NodeType, typename DepType>
constexpr std::array<NodeType, N> make_dep_array(std::array<DepType, N>& arr)
{
    return [&]<std::size_t...Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
        return std::array<NodeType, N>{{ NodeType(arr[Is])... }};
    }(std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```

Here is the complete code, using the `make_dep_array()` function:

```
/**
 * @file templ.cc
 * Compiles with:  c++ -std=c++17 -Wall templ.cc
 */

#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>

class Thing1
{
public:
    explicit Thing1(int v) noexcept : value(v) {}

    Thing1() noexcept                    = delete;
    Thing1(Thing1 const&)                = delete;
    Thing1(Thing1&&) noexcept            = delete;
    Thing1& operator=(Thing1 const&)     = delete;
    Thing1& operator=(Thing1&&) noexcept = delete;

    int value;
};

class Thing2
{
public:
    // Only this single parameter ctor is valid:
    explicit Thing2(Thing1& t1) noexcept: thing1(t1) {}

    Thing2() noexcept                    = delete;
    Thing2(Thing2 const&)                = delete;
    Thing2(Thing2&&) noexcept            = delete;
    Thing2& operator=(Thing2 const&)     = delete;
    Thing2& operator=(Thing2&&) noexcept = delete;

    Thing1& thing1;
};

template <std::size_t N, typename NodeType, typename DepType>
constexpr std::array<NodeType, N> make_dep_array(std::array<DepType, N>& arr)
{
    return [&]<std::size_t...Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
        return std::array<NodeType, N>{{ NodeType(arr[Is])... }};
    }(std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}

int main()
{
    constexpr size_t count = 4u;
    std::array<Thing1, count> thing1_pool = {Thing1(1), Thing1(2), Thing1(3), Thing1(4)};

    auto thing2_pool = make_dep_array<count, Thing2, Thing1>(thing1_pool);

    for (auto const& t: thing2_pool)
    {
        printf("%d\n", t.thing1.value);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe just add ```include <cstdio>``` for ```printf```. Apart from that, it works like a charm.